# jquery dropdown menu ITSELF on click with bootstrap-select plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-select

I have a dropdown menu and I want to call a function, when the `dropdown menu ITSELF` is clicked. I mean the part where you click on the dropdown menu `<select>` and all the available `<options>` are displayed.

```
<select id="p1" title="Select a thing" class="selectpicker show-tick" data-live-search="true">
    <option data-hidden="true"></option>
    <option>Select A</option>
    <option>Select B</option>
</select>
```

If I want to do something when Select A has been selected, I have the following.

```
$('#p1').change(function(event) {
    console.log("You selected an option");
});
```

But how to trigger something if the dropdown menu itself is clicked? I would like to load the `<option>` with data when the dropdown menu itself is clicked.

The following is not working:

```
$("#p1").click(function(){
    console.log("Loading <options>");
});
```

---

EDIT:
I found the problem. It is because I use a plugin called `bootstrap-select` https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

If I remove `class="selectpicker show-tick" data-live-search="true"` it works!

But how do I get on click working with the `bootstrap-select` plugin?

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/v257kjur/

Comment: What about to do it on focus?

Comment: This should be working as it is currently coded. As per Chris G above, it works fine in the fiddle he linked. Other than that, you could try on focus instead of on click

Comment: I found the "error". Please check my update to the question. It was because of the jquery plugin bootstrap-select.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your updated code, you can get the click event via the following:

HTML:

```
<select id="p1" title="Select a procedure" class="selectpicker show-tick" data-live-search="true">
    <option data-hidden="true"></option>
    <option>Select A</option>
    <option>Select B</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.bootstrap-select > button[data-id="p1"]').on('click', function (e) {
  console.log('clicked select');
});
```

Because BootstrapSelect replaces the select with divs and buttons, you'll have to target the correct button as I show above. Note that the ID of your select has now moved into the 'data-id' attribute of the button.

See this [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mqfLmwcn/). Sorry that the styling is messed but the functionality works at least.

Comment: I found the "error". Please check my update to the question. It was because of the jquery plugin bootstrap-select. How coul I get it working with the plugin?

Comment: Check my updated answer above for use with the plugin.

Comment: Don't forget to choose an accepted answer or update if the answers provided did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The normal `on click` did not work with the bootstrap-plugin. But they have some documentation regarding events: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/#events

```
//on click
$('#p1').on('show.bs.select', function (e) {
          console.log("hidden.bs.select means on click");
        });
```